# How to assign Array of values as keys to another array of values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

What is the Best way to convert,

```
{
   "columns":[
      "name",
      "color"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         "lion",
         "yellow"
      ],
      [
         "crow",
         "black"
      ]
   ]
}
```

into

```
{
   "data":[
      {
        "name":"lion",
        "color":"yellow"
      },
      {
         "name":"crow",
         "color":"black"
      }
   ]
}
```

Rather than loop, Is there any function available ? Can I achieved it through something like extend() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for the parts.

```js
var object = { columns: ["name", "color"], values: [["lion", "yellow"], ["crow", "black"]] },
    result = { data: object.values.map(v => Object.assign(...object.columns.map((c, i) => ({[c]: v[i]})))) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do do it with combination of map and reduce. Reducing original columns array will allow to code to work with any number of columns, it will pick up corresponding value by index:

```
const result = {data: data.values.map(el => {
  return data.columns.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    prev[curr] = el[index]
    return prev
  }, {})
})}
```

Check the demo below.

```js
const data = {
   "columns":[
      "name",
      "color"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         "lion",
         "yellow"
      ],
      [
         "crow",
         "black"
      ]
   ]
}

const result = {data: data.values.map(el => {
  return data.columns.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    prev[curr] = el[index]
    return prev
  }, {})
})}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get vales of `.columns` array using destructuring assignment, spread element; `for..of` loop to assign computed properties of `.columns` array as strings as properties of objects at `data` array by iterating `.values` property of original object, assign value of each array as value of created object

```js
let obj = {
   "columns":[
      "name",
      "color"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         "lion",
         "yellow"
      ],
      [
         "crow",
         "black"
      ]
   ]
}

let [res, key, value] = [{data:Array()}, ...obj.columns];

for (let [a, b] of [...obj.values]) res.data.push({[key]:a, [value]:b});

console.log(res);
```